# « illustrable » : dans quel contexte employez-vous ce mot ?

Tags: néologismes

Je ne retrouve pas ce mot dans beaucoup de dictionnaires, bien qu'il soit relativement couramment utilisé (on le retrouve sur le [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=illustrable%2C%20illustrables&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cillustrable%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cillustrables%3B%2Cc0)).

Il présente l'avantage d'être facilement compréhensible, et très pratique dans le sens où il permet d'alléger la structure « qui peut être illustré par ».

On retrouve sa définition dans [ce dictionnaire](http://www.notrefamille.com/dictionnaire/definition/illustrable) :

> Qui peut être illustré.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pour montrer un phénomène ou un problème (ou même tout autre chose).

> Ceci est illustrable par le graphisme suivant

Ou, comme vous le dites, pour remplacer « qui peut être illustré par » dans tous les contextes qui utilisent cette structure.

Comment: N'est-ce pas plutôt « graphique » vu le contexte qu'on présente ? Merci.

Comment: Tout dépend si tu montres un graphisme ou un graphique après :)

Answer (score 3):

Il se comprend, et je pourrais l'utiliser (en domaine technique), mais ça ressemble à un néologisme, ce que beaucoup de personnes peuvent trouver peu gracieux, et que les puristes trouveraient alors illicite. Le français n'est pas une langue très économe, et toute construction logique n'est pas forcement acceptée, au moins par les « littéraires » et les « classiques » (je me rappelle m'être fait reprocher le mot *poubelliser* en cours de français).

Answer (score 1):

*Illustrable* n'est pas un mot reconnu par l'Académie française (ni même par mon correcteur orthographique).

C'est une anglicisme qui est principalement utilisé dans les contextes de présentations techniques.

Pour une présentation en français soutenu, il est préférable d'utilisé *qui peut être illustré*, ou encore *dont l'illustration...*