# L'adjectif suffixé en -able peut-il servir à rendre l'action à laquelle réfère la possibilité qu'il exprime, dans une même phrase ?

Tags: sens, adjectifs, suffixes

Le filière des adjectifs en [*-able*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/-able) est [*productive*](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/16647). La question porte sur le sens de ce qui est produit et l'[emploi](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/16436) qu'on en fait. Ce genre d'adjectif peut-il servir à rendre l'action à laquelle réfère la possibilité qu'il exprime... dans la même phrase ?

---

On exprime *la possibilité passive* avec ce type d'adjectif, qui est surtout basé sur des verbes transitifs directs ; on ne peut le faire suivre d'un complément d'agent introduit par la préposition *par* (*critiquable pour certains* et non *par*) ; et on préfère le concevoir comme signifiant *« que l'on peut » + infinitif* plutôt que *« qui peut être » + participe passé* (*TLFi*). Mais cette équivalence de sens implique-t-elle qu'on puisse carrément substituer l'adjectif en *-able* pour réaliser le sens de l'action, tel que le fait le verbe, le participe passé ou l'infinitif ([*recycler*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=recycl%C3%A9%20*_ADP%2Crecyclable%20*_ADP%2Crecycler%20*_ADP&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Crecycl%C3%A9%20*_ADP%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Brecycl%C3%A9%20dans_ADP%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brecycl%C3%A9%20en_ADP%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brecycl%C3%A9%20%C3%A0_ADP%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brecycl%C3%A9%20par_ADP%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brecycl%C3%A9%20au_ADP%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brecycl%C3%A9%20pour_ADP%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brecycl%C3%A9%20de_ADP%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brecycl%C3%A9%20vers_ADP%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brecycl%C3%A9%20sur_ADP%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brecycl%C3%A9%20apr%C3%A8s_ADP%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Crecyclable%20*_ADP%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Brecyclable%20dans_ADP%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brecyclable%20%C3%A0_ADP%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brecyclable%20en_ADP%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brecyclable%20par_ADP%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Crecycler%20*_ADP%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Brecycler%20dans_ADP%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brecycler%20en_ADP%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brecycler%20%C3%A0_ADP%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brecycler%20pour_ADP%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brecycler%20au_ADP%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brecycler%20sur_ADP%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brecycler%20de_ADP%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brecycler%20par_ADP%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brecycler%20sans_ADP%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brecycler%20vers_ADP%3B%2Cc0) vs. [*recyclable*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/recyclable/67277?q=recyclable#66521), par exemple) ?

> (1) Ce contenant est recyclable *en
>   le déposant/par son dépôt* dans le bac prévu à cet effet. [x]
>  (2) Ce
>   contenant est recyclable *comme suit/ainsi/de la manière suivante* : en le déposant dans le bac prévu à cet effet. [x]

Je rejette spontanément ces constructions car elles me semblent outrepasser la [fonction](http://www.gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8872247) passive de ce genre d'adjectif, pour entrer directement dans le domaine de la réalisation de la possibilité ou du changement d'état, soit celui du verbe (*Ce contenant est recyclable. [On peut le recycler/on le recycle/il est recyclé] en le déposant dans le bac prévu à cet effet.*). Qu'en est-il ?

Answer (score 2):

L'exemple ne permet pas de donner des réponses parfaitement significatives car on ne recycle pas un objet en le déposant dans un bac. Le dépôt est seulement une première étape dans le processus de recyclage et ne fait que "contribuer au recyclage".

En reformulant les différentes possibilités ainsi:

> - (1) Ce contenant est recyclable. On peut contribuer à son recyclage en le déposant    dans le bac prévu à cet effet.
> - (2) Ce contenant est recyclable. On contribue à son recyclage en le déposant dans le bac prévu à cet effet.
> - (3) Ce contenant est recyclable. Il pourra être recyclé à condition de le déposer dans le bac prévu à cet effet.
> - (4) Ce contenant est recyclable en le déposant/par son dépôt dans le bac prévu à cet effet. [x]
> - (5) Ce contenant est recyclable comme suit/ainsi/de la manière suivante : en le déposant dans le bac prévu à cet effet. [x]

Ainsi modifiées, 1) 2) et 3) sont satisfaisantes et aucune des 3 possibilités ne s'impose par rapport aux autres (ce sera juste un choix personnel).

4) et 5) n'ont pas pu être reformulées parce ce n'est pas en le déposant dans le bac qu'on rend le produit recyclable. Le fait d'être recyclable dépend en amont de la composition/fabrication du produit et en aval de la filière de recyclage. Le fait de le déposer ou non dans un bac n'influe pas sur la nature recyclable du produit.

Comment: J'allais ajouter un commentaire sur la signification de recyclage. J'aurais même été plus catégorique en disant que le recyclage commence bien après le dépôt (c'est un peu comme dire qu'un article est achetable et qu'il peut être acheté en étant mis en rayon).

Comment: @Chop Utiliser le terme "contribuer" me choque personnellement. On dirait qu'on insiste volontairement sur le fait que ce n'est qu'une "petite" contribution... Personnellement, je dirais quelque chose du style: "Ce contenant est recyclable. Il peut être déposé dans le bac prévu à cet effet.". Pour le commun des mortels, on recycle en déposant le recyclable dans la poubelle recyclable (il est inutile de préciser que ce n'est pas la poubelle qui recycle toute seule...)

Comment: @Random - Je suis (comme *Chop*) en total désaccord sur le fait que "Pour le commun des mortels, on recycle en déposant le recyclable dans la poubelle recyclable".

Comment: @Random C'est effectivement une définition couramment acceptée, mais pas le véritable sens pour moi (ni pour [le Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/recycler), sauf si on considère que la poubelle est le début du prochain cycle, mais il ne commence alors pas au même endroit que le précédent). Ce qui est correct (toujours selon moi) est de dire que l'on trie les déchets pour permettre leur recyclage. Mais ceci n'est que digression (causée par ma faute, j'en suis conscient) qui nous éloigne de la question.

Answer (score 2):

Si cette question vous intéresse, je recommande la lecture de l'[enquête sur les dérivés en -able](http://redac.univ-tlse2.fr/lexiques/derives/Plenatetalii03c.pdf) de Hatout, Plénat & Tanguy (2003) qui montre que l'usage des dérivés récents dépasse largement la question de la possibilité passive.

Par ailleurs, parmi les dérivés classiques, *convenable* ou *nuisible* ne correspondent déjà pas à cette possibilité **passive** puisqu'il n'ont de forme passive ni l'un ni l'autre.

Comment: Merci ! Une lecture bien intéressante. Ref. : « [...] _peut être dit Xable tout élément intervenant dans le procès X, pour peu du moins que cet élément soit conçu comme se prêtant à la survenue du procès._ », bien _recycler_ est Xable, recyclable est réalisé etc. Ce n'est pas une curiosité comme l'_achat inhésitable_ ou un truc où on a plus de difficulté à identifier ce qui intervient. Oui il y a davantage que la possibilité passive, et c'est un bon point. Oui comme on voit ailleurs il y a _envoyer au recyclage_ et _recycler_ au sens strict. Par ailleurs, même si l'emploi pouvait être actif...

Comment: ... dans certains cas comme _survivable_ on est incertain quant à savoir si tel ou tel emploi est un anglicisme par exemple. Il peut donc y avoir une question d'emploi au-delà de la richesse de la réalisation du sens de l'adjectif _-able_. L'étude discute brièvement de ces sujets. Ma question est motivée par ma réaction à un truc comme « _une idée illustrable par le graphique suivant_ » où l'agent est directement impliqué (si je comprends bien). Je ne comprends pas qu'on puisse avoir la même construction avec le participe passé pour dire la même chose. C'est pas une question de productivité.